# MySQL Calendar with reminders

Tags: mysql, date

I'm developing an ajax web calendar with possibility to schedule events and reminders.

**The Schema**

```
id INT
title VARCHAR
startdate TIMESTAMP
endtime TIME
enddate DATE
kind INT
reminder INT DEFAULT 0
```

**The Explanation**

"kind" field could be 0,1,2,3,4,5 as "one time","daily","workdays","weekly","monthly","yearly"

"reminder" field is in minutes and means how many minutes before `startdate` the reminder should start to remind

I need to select events "on going" and reminders (there is no problem to mix both... I will split kind "real event"/"reminder" in php)

**The Select**

In this SELECT I will only consider "one time" (0) and "daily" (1) kind of schedules... (easier to let you understand)

```
SELECT * 
FROM calendar 
WHERE
    enddate >= NOW()
AND
(
    (
        NOW() >= startdate
        AND kind=0
        AND CURDATE() = DATE(startdate)
        AND CURTIME() <= endtime
    )
    OR
    (
        NOW() >= startdate
        AND kind=1
        AND CURTIME() >= TIME(startdate)
        AND CURTIME() <= endtime
    )
    OR
    ( 
        NOW() >= DATE_SUB(startdate, INTERVAL reminder MINUTE)
        AND NOW() < startdate 
    )
)
```

**The Problem**

I have no problem selecting events and reminder of "one time" kind, because reminder acts `**reminder**` minutes before `**startdate**` thru **DATE_SUB(startdate, INTERVAL reminder MINUTE)**

As you can see, the SELECT miss the reminders for kind=1 after the first schedule, because repetition means "every day between startdate end enddate", and reminder itself should repeat to appear.

I know I need to get the next schedule day/time and subtract `**reminder**`, but I didn't find the right solution till now... (remember that my "complete" SELECT should have workdays/weekly/monthly/yearly kind of schedules, than I need the right sql part to merge to other kind of schedules... but for this specific Question, I limit to daily reminders, just to not make difficult to understand what I am talking about! :D )

How to solve this? Help me please :(

Comment: Unless this is homework, it would be easier to select all rows for the user that could POSSIBLY apply, and then do datetime math outside of the database to determine which rows are relevant for the current time

Comment: it's not mysql efficient your solution... i know (and i've already made!) what you are talking about, but i want to get events and reminders as rows without any php "trick"...

Answer (score 0):

```
-- I suggest you to modify the table. Here is updated table structure

-- 
-- Table structure for table `reminder`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `reminder` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `startdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `enddate` date NOT NULL,
  `kind` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `reminder`
-- 

INSERT INTO `reminder` (`id`, `title`, `startdate`, `enddate`, `kind`) VALUES 
(1, 'This is reminder', '2015-06-03 19:25:44', '2015-07-21', 'weekly'); 


-- Query data get results for 2015-06-17 from  `reminder` table
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ','2015-06-17',TIME(startdate)) AS ReminderDateTime, title
                  FROM reminder  
                  WHERE IF(
                                        kind='daily',
                                        ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-06-17') -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(startdate))) % (1*24*60*60)=0)  ,
                                        IF(
                                            kind='weekly',
                                            ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-06-17') -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(startdate))) % (7*24*60*60)=0)  ,
                                            IF(
                                                kind='monthly',
                                                DAYOFMONTH('2015-06-17')=DAYOFMONTH(startdate),                         
                                                IF(
                                                    kind='quarterly',
                                                    ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-06-17') -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(startdate))) % (91*24*60*60)=0) ,
                                                    IF(
                                                        kind='yearly',
                                                        DAYOFYEAR('2015-06-17')=DAYOFYEAR(startdate),   
                                                        IF(
                                                            kind='',
                                                            startdate,
                                                            '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
                                                        )
                                                    )   
                                                )   
                                            )   
                                         )
                                        ) AND DATE(startdate) <='2015-06-17' AND IF(enddate<>'0000-00-00',enddate>='2015-06-17','1') ORDER BY ReminderDateTime ASC
```